# SVG Path is crawling / climbing up the page when screen size is small

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG on my page. This SVG is a white wave that creates a nice wave effect on the hero image for the page. But the SVG's Path (drawing) crawls up the page when the screen width decreases, creating a gap between itself and the hero image.

How do I align this SVG Path so it stays on the bottom?

```
.wave {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
border-radius: none;
}

<svg
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
    id="svg"
    viewBox="0 0 1440 1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    className="wave"
  >
    <path
      d="M 0,400 C 0,400 0,200 0,200 C 153.19999999999993,213.06666666666666 306.39999999999986,226.13333333333335 449,220 C 591.6000000000001,213.86666666666665 723.6000000000001,188.53333333333333 887,182 C 1050.3999999999999,175.46666666666667 1245.1999999999998,187.73333333333335 1440,200 C 1440,200 1440,400 1440,400 Z"
      stroke="none"
      stroke-width="0"
      fill="#ffffff"
    ></path>
  </svg>
```

[Here is an image of what is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eViRk.png)

Comment: maybe try adding preserveAspectRatio="none" Otherwise provide a more complete example i.e. with the hero image included or some proxy for that.

Comment: It's maintaining its aspect ratio, which is the default behaviour for svg's. Open the svg file and add preserveAspectRatio="none" to the svg element's attributes i.e. <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" .... etc etc. Then you can use css to do the rest.

Comment: Just saying: you have a viewBox where the height is 1: `viewBox="0 0 1440 1"`

Comment: @RobertLongson an image has been provided showing the problem.

Comment: Please update your question with a "working" [mcve].  I can see a couple of things already that might be wrong. But giving you an informed answer relies on seeing exactly what you are doing. Especially how the SVG is positioned relative to the hero image.

Comment: But the most likely cause, as @enxaneta says, is because your `viewBox` is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The size and scale of the `viewbox` (& graphics inside) is controlled by the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute on the svg.

By default, the viewbox is scaled uniformly to fit the size of the svg and centered horizontally and vertically. (Similar to how a background image would display with the following properties applied: `background-position: center center; background-size: contain;`)

This is why your path 'crawls up', the svg is positioned at the bottom of the hero but its contents is centered.

The `preserveAspectRatio` accepts two values, first is alignment, second (optional) is how it 'fits' inside the svg.

```
preserveAspectRatio="<align> [<meetOrSlice>]"
```

The mdn page about preserveAspectRatio is really helpful and gives a full list of examples. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

**tldr:**

To fix your issue, add `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet"` as an attribute of the SVG, EG:

```
<svg
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
    id="svg"
    viewBox="0 0 1440 234"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    className="wave"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet"
    >
...
</svg>
```

NB: The `viewBox`’s height needs to be big enough to contain the graphics, so has been increased. Kudos: [Sphinxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68936138#comment-121848261) & [enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68936138#comment-121792210).

Comment: For this to work properly, the `viewBox` must also be made taller to include the white wave, for example `0 0 1440 400`. Here is a nice introduction on how viewBox works: https://dev.to/lukejohnbrown/how-does-the-svg-viewbox-work-1cbh